# объясните по const_cast

Tags: c++, const-cast

Скажите вот читаю про const_cast.
написано const_cast позволяет лишить статуса const или volatile переменную .
Но такое ощущение , что не совсем ведь так буквально:
потому что рассматривать её как полноценную переменную я не могу :

```
    const int i = 0;
    const_cast<int*>(&i);
    i = 555;
```

но могу вот так :

```
    const int i = 0;
    int* j = const_cast<int*>(&i);
    *j = 555;
```

то есть , если объявлено const int i = 0;, то после const_cast i можно менять только при помощи указателя ?

Comment: Оно изменяет тип выражения, но не изменяет тип исходного объекта. Тип объекта в С/С++ всегда неизменяемый. Соответственно операции, которые можно проводить с результатом любого каста должны учитывать настоящий тип объекта. Попытка модифицировать объект с const квалификатором, как в `*j = 555;`, является неопределенным поведением.

Comment: Модификация во втором примере приводит к UB https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/const_cast

Comment: так если "попытка модифицировать объект с const квалификатором, как в *j = 555;, " это неопределенное повдение как пишет user7860670  , то какой смысл от const_cast, если первый мой пример бракует компилятор, а второй это UB ? честно говоря я не могу понять зачем надо константу делать переменной, ну да ладно. как тогда адекватно менять значение у константы после применения const_cast ?

Comment: @АндрейГуренков смысл `const_cast`: если возникла необходимость в нём, то понять, что проблема в дизайне/API, и, при возможности, поменять их; либо, если нельзя поменять, использовать `const_cast`, удостоверившись, что не будет модификации, и рассказав об этом в комментарии

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`const_cast` саму переменную не меняет. Он просто возвращает указатель, который вы ему передали, с измененным типом: вы передали ему `const int *`, а на выходе получили `int *`, указывающий на ту же переменную.

Конечно, если не использовать то, что этот каст возвращает, тогда он вообще ничего не делает.

Ваш второй пример, хотя и компилируется, тоже некорректен (вызывает неопределенное поведение), потому что вы модифицируете константную переменную.

`const_cast` можно использовать только чтобы модифицировать неконстантную переменную, если у вас почему-то есть только указатель-на-const (или константная ссылка) на нее.

Пример:

```
void f(const int *ptr)
{
    // *ptr = 42; // Ошибка, потому что в указателе `const`.
    *const_cast<int *>(ptr) = 42; // Ок.

}

int main()
{
    int foo = 0; // Ок.
    // const int foo = 0; // Не ок, неопределенное поведение из-за изменения константы.
    f(&foo);

}
```

Comment: Вот учебная задача, выходит условие её не корректно :
создайте const-массив double и volatile массив double. Переберите все элементы 
каждого массива в цикле, при помощи оператора const_cast отмените для каждого элементы 
const и volatile и присвойте ему значение.

Comment: @АндрейГуренков Да, оно действительно некорректно, если только вам не пытаются продемонстрировать, что это UB. Поругайте преподавателя за меня. :)

Comment: надо найти Брюса Эккеля и поругать . потому что задача от туда . книга 2004 года)))

Comment: @АндрейГуренков Значит ошибка в книге (если рядом нигде не написано, что будет UB, опять же).

Comment: понятие UB вообще не вводилось.

Answer (score 6):

Присваивать объекту, который был определён как `const` — это в любом случае *UB* (*undefined behavior*). `const_cast` ни коим образом не снимает константность с самого объекта, он только «возвращает» переданное ему значение с нужным типом (это выражение также может быть «присваиваемым» (*l-value*)).

На практике `const_cast` используется довольно редко. Обычно это относительно грязный хак, чтобы передать константный объект в функцию, которая заведомо его не меняет (но принимает неконстантную ссылку/указатель) или, наоборот, изменить объект заведомо созданные как неконстантный, но переданный по константной ссылке/указателю. В тривиальном варианте это выглядит как-то так:

```
void foo (const int &i) {
  const_cast<int &>(i) = 2;
}

void bar (int *i) {
  std::cout << *i;
}

// ...

int i=0;
const int ci=2;

foo(i);
bar(const_cast<int*>(&ci));
```

---

По непосредственному вопросу: с точки зрения синтаксиса можно привести константную переменную к неконстантной ссылке (само собой так делать не стоит):

```
const int i = 0;
const_cast<int&>(i) = 2;  // !! UB !!
```